# Feed Me - Importing CSV Fails

Tags: plugin-feedme

I am trying to import a few reasonably straightforward fields to populate some entries from a CSV. It seems to run ok but nothing comes through and when I look a the logs I get the error below - anyone know what this means?

`The shell command "mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="C:\Users\Malcolm\Google Drive\CRAFT-SITES\marshall-bridge\storage\runtime\temp\my.cnf" --add-drop-table --comments --create-options --dump-date --no-autocommit --routines --set-charset --triggers --single-transaction --no-data --result-file="C:\Users\Malcolm\Google Drive\CRAFT-SITES\marshall-bridge\storage\backups/feedme-190524_100041_cdm7gla482.sql" marshall-bridge && mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="C:\Users\Malcolm\Google Drive\CRAFT-SITES\marshall-bridge\storage\runtime\temp\my.cnf" --add-drop-table --comments --create-options --dump-date --no-autocommit --routines --set-charset --triggers --no-create-info --ignore-table=marshall-bridge.assetindexdata --ignore-table=marshall-bridge.assettransformindex --ignore-table=marshall-bridge.sessions --ignore-table=marshall-bridge.templatecaches --ignore-table=marshall-bridge.templatecachequeries --ignore-table=marshall-bridge.templatecacheelements --ignore-table=marshall-bridge.cache --ignore-table=marshall-bridge.templatecachecriteria marshall-bridge >> "C:\Users\Malcolm\Google Drive\CRAFT-SITES\marshall-bridge\storage\backups/feedme-190524_100041_cdm7gla482.sql"" failed with exit code 1. - Connection.php: 58`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a manual back up of your database and then disable Database back up on the feed settings.

If you're using MAMP, [this could be your issue](https://craftcms.com/guides/database-backups-in-craft-3-with-mamp).